# Derivative of integral with time varying domain

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Let  $A(t) \subset \mathbb{R}^p$ be varying with time $t$. Is there a nice expression for
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{A(t)}f(x) dx$$
?

Comment: It depends on the form of $A$.

Comment: For a certain real vector $c$ and $r>0$: $A(t)=\{||x+tc||\leq r \ | \ x \in \mathbb{R}^p\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $A(t) = \bar{B}(tc,r)$. Let $\phi(\delta) = tc+\delta$. Then $\phi(\bar{B}(0,r)) = A(t)$. Note that $D\phi(\delta) = I$, so by the change of variables theorem, we have
$g(t) = \int_{A(t)} f(x) dx = \int_{\phi(\bar{B}(0,r))} f(x) dx = \int_{\bar{B}(0,r)} f(\phi(y))\, |1|\,dy = \int_{\bar{B}(0,r)} f(tc+y) dy$.

Now, assuming that $f$ is sufficiently smooth, you have
$Dg(t) = \int_{\bar{B}(0,r)} Df(tc+y)\,c\, dy = (\int_{A(t)} Df(x) dx)c$.

Comment: What is $Df$? ..

Comment: $Df(x) = \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$.

Comment: $x$ is a vector

Comment: I understand. That is why I went through the above manipulations. How do you usually write derivatives?

Comment: $c$ is a vector, hence $Df(x)$ must also be a vector. Do you mean that $Df(x)=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2},\ldots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_p})$ ?

Comment: Yes. That is what $Df(x), \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$ usually mean.

Comment: Note that the above works because the set $A(t)$ is particularly 'nice'.

Comment: Suppose $f$ is the density function of a zero mean multivariate normal vector with uncorrelated components (covariance is a diagional matrix), can you show that $g'(t)\leq 0$ ?

Comment: That would be a matter of working out $Df(x)$ and substituting into the above formula.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11614/discussion-between-nadori-and-copper-hat)

Comment: I went there and waited, but no luck. This is probably better posed as another question.

Comment: check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575420/negative-derivative-of-integral-with-time-varying-domain

Comment: Why the downvote? Please let me know if there is something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the Reynolds Transport Theorem.

https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Reynolds_transport_theorem