# negative derivative of integral with time varying domain?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Show  that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{A(t)}f(x) dx \leq 0 $$
where $f$ is the density function of a zero mean multivariate normal vector with covariance $D=diag(d_1,\ldots,d_p)$ and
 $A(t)=\{||x+tc||\leq r \ | \ x \in \mathbb{R}^p\}$ for a certain real vector $c$, $r>0$ and $t\geq 0$.

This question is discussed here [Derivative of integral with time varying domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575058/derivative-of-integral-with-time-varying-domain) for a part.

Hence it comes down to show that
$$\int_{\overline{B}(0,r)} D^{-1}(y+tc)\cdot c \exp(-1/2 (y+tc)'D^{-1}(y+tc)) dy \ \geq 0$$ 
with $D^{-1}(y+tc)=(\frac{y_1+tc_1}{d_1},\ldots,\frac{y_p+tc_p}{d_p})'$.

**Edit:** Question 2.It is clear that the derivative at $t=0$ is zero. I want to prove that the expression has a local maximum at $t=0$, which means that we need to show that the second derivative in $t=0$ is negative, which is equivalent to 
$$\int_{\overline{B}(0,r)} c'D^{-1}c\  \exp(-1/2 y'D^{-1}y) \ dy \geq \int_{\overline{B}(0,r)} (y'D^{-1}c)^2 \  \exp(-1/2 y'D^{-1}y) \ dy.$$

Can someone suggest a way to prove the above inequality?

Comment: How can this be true, even in one dimension? There must be more constraints. In this case, the integral becomes $\int_{[tc-r,tc+r]} f$ which is not a decreasing function of $t$. It goes to zero for large $|t|$, and is maximized at $t=0$.

Comment: t is nonzero, I have edited the question

Comment: Altough I had already mention that t is time